# Unpredictable errors VBA microsoft word copying comments and text to excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I tried to make a macro that takes all the comments in a word document, filters based on the comment text and then inserts them in excel with the associated text in a note.

I tried each step iteratively and I managed to copy the comments and pasting the wanted results in the same word document. Then I managed to manipulate excel by adding columns and notes.

Everything broke when I integrated the excel part with the comment extraction part. The errors were `invalid procedure call` for the line with `rightParPos = InStr(leftParPos, comment, ")")` which I hadn't touched in a while, so I tried outputting the parameters... That lead to a completely different error - an indexing error for the `categories` array when `categoryCount` was 0, which also was very strange. After that I tried removing a strange character in a string and then I suddenly got some kind of "can't connect to excel" at `Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=xlPath)`.

It seems completely random to me. I'm thinking that it might be some kind of limit or bug in the Microsoft Word environment that is causing these problems. Anyone knowing what could be a cause of these strange errors?

I couldn't find anything out of the ordinary with my code, but maybe someone on S.O. sees something that immediately looks strange. Sorry for the very messy code.

```vb
Sub Test()
    Dim comment, text As String
    Dim pageNr As Integer
    Dim codePrefix, fileName As String
    Dim newLinePos, leftParPos, rightParPos As Integer
    Dim commentNr As Integer
    Dim codeWorksheetIndex As Integer
    Dim xlFile, xlDir, xlPath As String
    
    'Excel'
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlWB As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Err Then
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    xlFile = "TEST"
    xlDir = "My\Directory\path\" 'censored
    xlPath = xlDir & xlFile
    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=xlPath)

    codePrefix = "a-code" 'censored
    fileName = Left(ActiveDocument.Name, Len(ActiveDocument.Name)-5)

    'insert a column as second column in each spreadsheet'
    For sheet_index = 1 to 3
        With xlWB.Worksheets(sheet_index)
            .Range("B:B").Insert
            .Cells(1, 2).Formula = fileName
        End With
    Next sheet_index

    For commentNr = 1 To ActiveDocument.Comments.Count
        Dim category As String
        Dim categories(1 to 2) As String
        Dim categoryCount As Integer
        Dim numLeft, numRight as Integer
        'Dim j As Integer
       
        comment = LCase(ActiveDocument.Comments(commentNr).Range)
        text = ActiveDocument.Comments(commentNr).Scope
        pageNr = ActiveDocument.Comments(commentNr).Scope.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)

        'find newline'
        newLinePos = InStr(comment, vbCr)

        If newLinePos = 0 Then
            newLinePos = InStr(comment, vbLf)
            If newLinePos = 0 Then
                newLinePos = InStr(comment, vbCrLf)
                if newLinePos = 0 then
                    newLinePos = InStr(comment, Chr(10))
                    if newLinePos = 0 then
                        ActiveDocument.Content.InsertAfter Text:="ERROR: comment " & commentNr & " misses newline!" & vbNewLine
                    End If
                End If 
            End If
        End If 

        'set to initial index for leftpar instr'
        rightParPos = 1
        categoryCount = 0

        Do

            leftParPos = InStr(rightParPos, comment, "(")
            rightParPos = InStr(leftParPos, comment, ")")

            If leftParPos > 0 and rightParPos > 0 Then
                numLeft = rightParPos-1
                numRight = numLeft - leftParPos
                category = Trim(Right(Left(comment, numLeft), numRight))

                categories(categoryCount) = category

                categoryCount = categoryCount + 1
            End If
        Loop While leftParPos > 0 And rightParPos > 0

        comment = fileName & " (s. " & pageNr & ")" & vbNewLine & Trim(Right(comment, Len(comment)-newLinePos))

        If Instr(LCase(comment), codePrefix) = 1 Then

            For categoryIndex = 0 To categoryCount-1

                category = categories(categoryIndex)

                If category = "category1" Then
                    codeWorksheetIndex = 1
                ElseIf category = "category2" Then
                    codeWorksheetIndex = 2
                ElseIf category = "category3" Then
                    codeWorksheetIndex = 3
                End If

                With xlWB.Worksheets(codeWorksheetIndex)
                    .Cells(commentNr+1, 2).Formula = text
                    .Cells(commentNr+1, 2).NoteText comment 'this only worked without =
                End With
            Next categoryIndex

        End If

    Next commentNr

End Sub
```

Comment: `rightParPos = InStr(leftParPos, comment, ")")` will fail with that error if `leftParPos` is -1, which will happen if `comment` doesn't contain "(".  You need to check for that case.

Comment: @TimWilliams True, I'll fix that and see if something improves. (small correction though: the string methods are 1-indexed and it returns 0 instead of -1).

Answer (score 0):

There are two critical problems with the code that were overlooked and then there was one third problem that wasn't due to the code but which also resulted in errors.

1. As @TimWilliams mentioned, one case where `leftParPos = 0` was unhandled.
2. The indexing of `categories` was entirely wrong and faulty in the code.
3. The strangest error was due to having the excel file on an external harddrive that disconnected and therefore making excel not responding.